# Find all word with a #

Tags: python

I want to find all words which have a # attached to it.
I tried:

```
import re
text = "I was searching my #source to make a big desk yesterday."
re.findall(r'\b#\w+', text)
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
re.findall(r"#.+?\b", text)
```

which gives:

```
['#source']
```

---

Here is a link to [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/UHxuYA/1) which gives in-depth insight into what each part does.

---

Basically what is happening is:

- the `#` means capture the `'#'` character literally
- then we say to match any character with a `.`
- but the `+` signifies to capture *one or more* of them
- then the `?` begins a non-greedy match to whatever follows
- the `\b` is a word boundary and signifies when to stop the lookup

---

**Update**

As pointed out by `@AnthonySottile`, there is a case where the above `regex` will fail, namely:

```
hello#fred
```

where a match is made when it shouldn't be.

To get around this problem, a `/s` could be added to the front of the `regex` so as to make sure the `#` comes after some whitespace, but this fails in the case where the hashtag comes right at the start of the string. A `/b` also won't suffice as the `#` makes the hashtag not count as a word.

So, to get around these, I came up with this rather ugly solution of adding a space to the start of the string before doing the `findall`:

```
re.findall(r"\s(#.+?)\b", " " + text)
```

---

It's not very neat I know but there really isn't another way of doing it. I tried using an `OR` at the start to match a whitespace or the start of the string, as in `(^|\s)`, but this will produce multiple groups (as tuples) in the list that is returned from `re.findall` so would requires some post-processing which is *even less* neat.

Comment: @totyped Sorry, need to escape the `#`,  one sec!

Comment: @totyped Have a go now!

Comment: Works now ! Thanks

Comment: Fails (presumably) for this testcase: `'a#b'` (should not match)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Nice spot! I have updated the answer now to make sure that a whitespace character comes before the `#`...

Comment: @AnthonySottile I have updated the `regex`, but as my note at the bottom says, it's not great :/ If you have any ideas on how to improve it, please say.

Comment: Here's what I came up with, though the split solution below if far more elegant imo: `re.findall(r'(?:[^\w]|^)(#\w+)', text)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small regex to do that:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I was searching my #source to make a big desk yesterday."
>>> re.findall(r"#(\w+)", s)
['source']
```

If you want to include the hashtag then use:

```
>>> re.findall(r"#.\w+", s)
['#source']
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regex to solve this problem:

```
text = "I was searching my #source to make a big desk yesterday."
final_text = [i for i in text.split() if i.startswith('#')]
```

Output:

```
['#source']
```

However, this regex will work:

```
import re
text = "I was searching my #source to make a big desk yesterday."
final_text = filter(lambda x:x, re.findall('(?<=^)|(?<=\s)#\w+(?=\s)|(?=$)', text))
```

Output:

```
['#source']
```

Comment: Nice complete answer !